# Trying to move a file from a python client to a c# server

Tags: c#, python, sockets, readfile

I am trying to copy a jpg image from a c# server in one PC to a python client in another.
The idea is simply to read the image content:

```
        string text = File.ReadAllText(newPath);
        //or
        byte[] text = File.ReadAllBytes(newPath);
```

and to send the text with:

```
                Byte[] sendBytes = text
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkStream.Flush();
```

and the python client recieves the text and save it into a jpg file right away.

I know it's sound crazy, **but it worked!** I saw it in another server and wanted to know how did they do it.

I looked for a solution for days, but I still recieve only part of the data all the time (if the file is 7.78 MB, I recieve only 7.74 MB).

I already checked for dupicate posts here, and all I found was transfering files from same language server to the same language client.

I tried using `StreamReader` and `BitConverter`, but still I get only part of the image, not all of it.

The python code to save the image that recieved is:

```
    rcvdD = socketPCP.recv(512000000) #I thought that the recv Size is causing to the problem
    try:
            filename = "image.jpg"
            print "NAME:",filename
            print "\n\r\n\rNEW FILE RECIEVED!\n\r\n\r"
            f=open ('D:/Files/'+filename , 'w')
            f.write(rcvdD)
    except Exception,e:
            print e
```

Thank You!

Comment: Ok Ive succeeded to send the image, but I still can't view it correctly, I can see it corrupted, I think that has something to do with the python recieve size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good at python, but as I remember you should keep recv()-ing appending each chunk in a final buffer until you receive a zero length data or an error, then write to disk what you got in that buffer.

Comment: Yes I tried that:

while true:

    data = socket.recv(1)
    if not data: break
    totaldata += data

but still it didn't worked.

Comment: Read this [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408859-socketrecv-three-ways-to-turn-it-into-recvall/) to see a good explanation about recvall in python.